What subset of the Lorentz group produces a given Weyl spinor?
Let's say I have a unit Weyl spinor $\psi = [\psi_1\ \psi_2]^T$.  This has 3 degrees of freedom.  Now suppose that this spinor was produced from a reference unit spinor — let's take $[1\ 0]^T$ to be the reference for now — by the action of an element $M$ of $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$.  This means the first column of $M$ is simply $\psi$, and the second column is arbitrary apart from the scaling condition $\det(M) = 1$.  This places $M$ in a particular subset $S$ of $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$, which I believe is 2-dimensional, since the 2nd column of $M$ originally had 4 degrees of freedom but the determinant condition knocks off two of them.  Also, I don't think $S$ is a subgroup, as the first column will not generally be preserved under multiplication.
To what subset of the Lorentz group does $S$ correspond, under the double-covering map of $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ onto the Lorentz group?  More generally, what class of subsets of the Lorentz group would be possible if we let the reference spinor be arbitrary?

The different Weyl spinors belong to different fundamental representations of $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb C)$ the do not mix under transformation. More concretely, let $\begin{pmatrix} \psi \\ \bar \chi\end{pmatrix}$ be a Dirac Spinor in Weyl basis. For $S \in \operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb C)$ the Weyl spinors transform according to
\begin{align}
\psi &\mapsto S \psi\\
\bar \chi &\mapsto S^{-1}{}^\dagger \bar \chi\,.
\end{align}
Note, that both transformations define a left action. In particular, if you start from $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ the lower entry will always be $0$, so you cannot get arbitrary Dirac spinors this way.

Thanks for the answer, however I think there's a misunderstanding.  I'm not asking about Dirac spinors at all, just individual Weyl spinors.  By $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ I mean a Weyl spinor whose complex entries are 1 and 0.  Now take all elements of $SL(2,\mathbb C)$ that transform that spinor to another given Weyl spinor $\begin{pmatrix} \psi_1 \ \psi_2 \end{pmatrix}$.  To what subset of the Lorentz group does that subset of $SL(2, \mathbb C)$ correspond?
